# How can I fetch data from a website to my local Django Website?

Tags: django, python-requests

I am rather new to Django and I need to fetch some data from a website. For example I want the top ten posts of the day from Reddit. I know of a "request" module for the same.But I am not sure where and how should I implement it and will it be important to store the data in a model or not.

Comment: You definitely can! But this question is very broad. I suggest you [learn](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) the ```requests``` library and try to write the code, and ask questions if you have any problems there.

Comment: Yes I have, but I am unable to understand as to where in my Django application do I call and implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a helper class named like `network.py` and implement functions to fetch the data.

If you want to store them in the database you can create appropriate models otherwise you can directly import and call the function and use the data returned from `network.py` in your view.